# The interpretation of cross validation scores

Tags: cross-validation

I am trying to understand this part of code that I found on the Internet:

```
kfold = KFold(n_splits=7, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, x, y, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

What the does `cross_val_score`?
I know that it calculates scores. I want to understand the meaning of these scores, and how they are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working of cross_val_score:

1. As seen in [source code of cross_val_score](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L137), this `x` you supplied to `cross_val_score` will be divided into `X_train, X_test` using `cv=kfold`. Same for y.
2. `X_test` will be held back and `X_train` and `y_train` will be passed on to `estimator` for `fit()`.
3. After fitting, `estimator` will then be scored using `X_test` and `y_test`.
4. The **steps 1 to 3 will be repeated** for folds specified in `kfold` and array of scores will returned from `cross_val_score`.

Explanation of 3rd point:  Scoring depends on the estimator and `scoring` param in cross_val_score. In your code here, you have not passed any scorer in `scoring`. So default `estimator.score()` will be used.

If `estimator` is a classifier, then `estimator.score(X_test, y_test)` will return [accuracy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html). If its a regressor, then [R-squared](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) is returned.

Comment: I see, so depending on the scoring parameter of the cross_val_score it calculates scores. I have another question, after calculating the scores, I see that it calculates also the MSE. Can you clarify how the MSE is calculated using the scores?

Comment: @A.Arfaoui In that case, you have to use the scoring function to return mse in the first place. After that you can take the mean as you are doing in your code.